# how to get value of selected item in autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, autocomplete

i have here a code from http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ it works really good but i cant find a way to get the value of selected item in the text view i tried something like this but its not working

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tags').change(function () {
        $('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + this.value);
    }).change();
});
</script>

<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tags').change(function () {
        $('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + this.value);
    }).change();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" />
  <div id="tagsname"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data - check this url

Comment: dont use `.ready()` in jQM.

Comment: @Omar what do you suggest is a better idea?

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html im reading this one get to you later if i have problems thank you.do you mind if i ask what is the advantage of using JQM event than .ready?will it affect so many things?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/killwithme/ke8osq27/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When autocomplete changes a value, it fires a [autocompletechange](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change) event, not the change event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tags').on('autocompletechange change', function () {
        $('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + this.value);
    }).change();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TyP5c/)

Another solution is to use [select](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) event, because the change event is triggered only when the input is blurred

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tags').on('change', function () {
        $('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + this.value);
    }).change();
    $('#tags').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
        $('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + ui.item.value);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kPLew/)

Comment: But when blur event is called on text box then only we get output right

Comment: its working but when i change the item the value in tagsname remain the same how should i refresh this? and delay is so long is there a way to make the delay shorter?

Comment: @ArunPJohny i did its very nice but is there a way when i choose an item the value will automatically show its taking some time before it shows but its ok  if it like that now i see what you mean that was really nice

Answer (score 23):

To answer the question more generally, the answer is:

```
select: function( event , ui ) {
    alert( "You selected: " + ui.item.label );
}
```

Complete example :

```js
$('#test').each(function(i, el) {
    var that = $(el);
    that.autocomplete({
        source: ['apple','banana','orange'],
        select: function( event , ui ) {
            alert( "You selected: " + ui.item.label );
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Type a fruit here: <input type="text" id="test" />
```

Comment: I think this is complete answer

Comment: I agree with this answer since it uses the event callback provided by the Autocomplete component. No need to use jQuery on event binding.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tags').on('change', function () {
        $('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + this.value);
    }).change();
    $('#tags').on('blur', function (e, ui) {
        $('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + ui.item.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something pretty close to this - the moment a user picks an item, even by just hitting the arrow keys to one (focus), I want that data item attached to the tag in question. When they type again without picking another item, I want that data cleared.

```
(function() {
    var lastText = '';

    $('#MyTextBox'), {
        source: MyData
    })
    .on('autocompleteselect autocompletefocus', function(ev, ui) {
        lastText = ui.item.label;
        jqTag.data('autocomplete-item', ui.item);
    })
    .keyup(function(ev) {
        if (lastText != jqTag.val()) {
            // Clear when they stop typing
            jqTag.data('autocomplete-item', null);

            // Pass the event on as autocompleteclear so callers can listen for select/clear
            var clearEv = $.extend({}, ev, { type: 'autocompleteclear' });
            return jqTag.trigger(clearEv);
    });
})();
```

With this in place, 'autocompleteselect' and 'autocompletefocus' still fire right when you expect, but the full data item that was selected is always available right on the tag as a result. 'autocompleteclear' now fires when that selection is cleared, generally by typing something else.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so in my particular case I had multiple text inputs which used the same class, all of which utilized jQuery Autocomplete with the same autocomplete data set.

Since all these inputs would require their values to be set in order to be successfully submitted via $_POST, I was baffled as to why the selected value would not be set for the value attribute of each input after selecting a value from the predefined autocomplete list.

After a lot of back and forth, and since all mentioned inputs shared the same core class, this is what I ended up doing:

```
// setup autcomplete
$('.sample-input').autocomplete({

    // define source data
    source: autocomp_data,

    // setup input event as per docs
    select: function(event, ui) {

        // set the target element
        let target = $(this);

        // retrieve selected value from event
        let selected = ui.item.value;

        // set target value using .attr (using .val() does not work, for some reason)
        target.attr('value', selected);
    }
});
```

In this way I was actually able to set the correct value for each input and get submission via $_POST to work. Not sure *why* jQuery UI Autocomplete does not do this by default (I'm sure some guru on SE knows), but yes, the above snippet solved the problem for me.