# How to display the element after selecting from autocomplete list using Event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-autocomplete

I want to display the Element just after selecting from autocomplete list.

My Code :

```
  $(function () {

                $("#SearchString").autocomplete({
                    messages: '',
                    source: '@Url.Action("GetProducts","Search")',
                    minLength: 2,

                });
          });

<div id="search" style="display:inline">

 @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchProduct", "Search", FormMethod.Post, "null"))
 {

        @Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new { id = "SearchString" })

        <input type="submit" value="Search" id="Search" />
}

</div>
```

Please share your suggestions.

Comment: you mean the selected value should be displayed ?

Comment: @dreamweiver Yes, by just clicking on the selected element from the autocomplete list

Comment: Refer to this SO ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675069/how-to-get-value-of-selected-item-in-autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `select` event of autocomplete:

```
$("#SearchString").autocomplete({
                    messages: '',
                    source: '@Url.Action("GetProducts","Search")',
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function (i, j) 
                    {
                    alert(j.item.value);
                    }

                });
```

See the autocomplete [**documentation**](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) for details

[**Fiddle Example HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3u6vE/)