# Execute function on option selected from jQuery ui autocomplete option list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Hi I have the code below for autocomplete which works fine but my only issue is that when a user clicks on an option from the autocomplete list, it should trigger another function (doSomething()). This however is not being done. Granted if the user makes a selection and presses **"enter"** the function is executed.

```
var url = "http://myURL";
var field = "myField";

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#tags").autocomplete({  
      source: function (req, add) {
          var suggestions = search(req.term, url, field);
          add(suggestions);  
      },
       select: function( event, ui ) {
        doSomething();          
  }
  });

 });  


function search(value, listurl, field) {
  var coll = new Array();
  var url =  
      listurl + "?$filter=startswith(" + field + ",'" + value + "')";

  $.ajax({
      cache: true,
      type: "GET",
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      url: url,  
      success: function (data) {
          var results = data.d.results;
          for (att in results) {
              var object = results[att];
              for (attt in object) {
                  if (attt == field) {
                      coll.push(object[attt]);
                  }
              }
          }
      }

  });
  return coll;}

function doSomething() {
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can't you assign callback function directly as `select: doSomething`

Comment: @log1c I tried that but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this resolved like this:

```
$('#tags').on('keyup change', function () {
        doSomething();
    }).change();

$('#tags').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
    doSomething();
    });
```

Thanks to this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675069/how-to-get-value-of-selected-item-in-autocomplete/%22SO%20link%22)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old topic, but I came across this problem and I found another solution which I believe JQuery provides for. You can use the `close` event to do this.

Examples (extracted from http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ and adapted for this question):

1) When you initialize the autocomplete

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  close: function( event, ui ) { doSomething(); }
});
```

or

2) Binding an listener to the close event

```
$( "#tags" ).on( "autocompleteclose", function( event, ui ) { doSomething(); } );
```