# bootstrap auto complete with typehead

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hello everyone,
                I have integrated bootstrap typehead for autocomplete using textbox. It's working fine, I am selecting company name using auto complete feature ,now how to get the company id for the same company name(company_id already exist in database).So which textbox event I have to use  query to get company id corresponding to company name. As soon as he selects company name I have to enable/disable some select box based on this.

html part

```
<input type="text" name="project_company" class="project_company" size="40" class="typeahead-devs" placeholder="Please Enter Day Name">
```

jQuery part

```
$('input.project_company').typeahead({
    name: 'project_company',
    remote: 'http://localhost/exp/includes/autocomplete?query=%QUERY'
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: an output of the remote call would be helpful

Comment: I tried following  solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675069/how-to-get-value-of-selected-item-in-autocomplete  but still not getting the values

Comment: @Nozzleman I want only one company name which is selected not all the values

Comment: @Akshobhya post what that query returns.