# Ajax call to dynamically populate dropdown works in FF, but not in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I really don't know why my code works perfectly in Firefox, but when I test it in Chrome or IE, it doesn't populate a dynamic dropdown. I read some similar posts, but most of them said it's because of an unclosed div which I don't have!

Here is the code:

```
<html> 
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
</head>

<body>    
<input type="textbox" name= "tag" id="tags">
<p>
<select id="movieImdbId" name="movieImdbId[]" multiple="multiple" width="200px" size="10px" style=display:none;>
</select>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: "actorsauto.php",  //php file which fetch actors name from DB
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui){
                var selectedVal = $(this).val(); 
                // Here goes your ajax call.      
                $.post("actions.php", {q: selectedVal}, function (response){
                    // response variable above will contain the option tags.            
                    $("#movieImdbId").html(response).show();
                });
            }
        });     
    });        
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do the dev tools in Chrome and IE have any errors in them? What's a sample value for `response`?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: I am not sure if I get your point, when I press F12 in chrome, It shows me this error in console: `failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`, `GET http://localhost/res/images/ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: The developer tools show all kinds of errors, including trying to load resources (in this case an image) that can't be loaded for whatever reason (the server is down, the URL is incorrect, etc). Run the AJAX call (from your autocomplete) with the developer tools open and see what you get back; in Chrome you want to be looking at the Network tab.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: thnaks, but I don't understand if it has errors why it works in firefox?

Comment: If there are errors, what do they say? That might explain why it works in Firefox but not the others, or might not.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: In developer tools (in console), I get this as soon as I enter the page containing the code I wrote in my question: http://localhost/res/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: but I don't get a new error when I insert actor name to dynamically populate dropdown of movies.. (It does not populate a dropdown but I don't see any error in console too)

Comment: Can you post a sample response from the AJAX call? Might be caused by slightly incorrect HTML that Chrome and Firefox are handling differently.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: sorry, I don't know what you mean by sample of response? :| do u mean s.th like this? (when I am in FF, I get this response in console.log: `"<option value="Forrest Gump">Forrest Gump</option><option value="Saving Private Ryan">Saving Private Ryan</option><option value="The Green Mile">The Green Mile</option><option value="Toy Story">Toy Story</option><option value="Toy Story 3">Toy Story 3</option><option value="Catch Me If You Can">Catch Me If You Can</option><option value="Cast Away">Cast Away</option><option value="Toy Story 2">Toy Story 2</option>...`

Comment: for example when I insert an actor name like "tom hanks", it should dynamically populate a dropdown which contains the list of movies by "tom hanks".. however, I don't get any response in chrome and IE.. it only works in ff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675069/how-to-get-value-of-selected-item-in-autocomplete), I could finally solved my problem by just using  [autocompletechange event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change), instead of change event.

So This is the code worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: "actorsauto.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui){
$("#tags").on('autocompletechange change', function (){
var selectedVal = $(this).val();      //this will be your selected value from autocomplete

                    $.post("actions.php", {q: selectedVal}, function (response){

                    $("#movieName").html(response).show();

                });
              }).change();
    }
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try to Explicitly Map your response here's an example from my code change to be applicable

From your post request return a json object, with two values, the label, what you want to display from the autocomplete and the value, what value you want to associate with that label, in this example I saved the value in a property (.url) as the value because I wanted my autocomplete to sync to a url.

The response function binds your results to the control.  It takes in the  [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) a jquery delegate which maps the array to the required structure (label is mapped to templab item.label (a property I serialized in json from the post)) 
(value is mapped to the item.url).

I'm not sure if this will solve your porblem but now you will be explicitly binding your data

```
success: function (data) {
    response($.map(data, function (item) {
    // this line below is a hack to get out the html encoded entities (&gt; &lt;...)
    var templab = $('#searchhtmlconverter').html(item.label).text();
    return { label: templab, value: item.url };
     }))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry I am not good in javascript, could you please explain a little your code? (I didn't understand what exactly I have to change or add in my own code) Thanks