# Jqueryui autocomplete, get selected user id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

im new to jquery ui autocomplete. Im basically using autocomplete with ajax, with PHP to get list of users.

autocompleteajax.js

```
$(function() {
    $( "#ranksearch" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            console.log('in');
            $.ajax({
                url: "autocompleteajax.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    q: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    console.log(request);
                    console.log(data);
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
    });
});
```

and the JSON, that php is returning looks like this

```
{3: "Tomek To", 4: "Tomek Kula"}
```

The number is userid, and the string is Firstname Lastname. I would like to store the selected userid somewhere, after someone chooses it from autocomplete list. Is there any simple way to achieve it?

Comment: Duplicate possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675069/how-to-get-value-of-selected-item-in-autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help @Dev.Joel i found out the solution.

In php i stored users like this

```
$users[] = array('value'=>$uid,'label'=>$uname);
```

Then the i got the values in js by doing this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ranksearch').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the "value" being written back after we've done our own changes

        this.label = ui.item.label;

        $('#ranksearch').val(this.label);
        console.log(ui.item.value);
    });
});
```

Something was broken meanwhile i did this and i had to assign myself the label to input, since it was using value.