# How to pass the dynamic value of id to jquery which I get from json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I got the values from json and pass to the autocomplete search field.

```
[{"id":1,"name":"JAVA"},{"id":2,"name":"cake PHP"},"id":3,"name":"Android"}]
```

For example, when I click the `JAVA`, I want to get the id of JAVA like *www.example.com/1*

Jquery code:

```
<script>
$('#search').typeahead({ 
ajax: '/searchendpoint/search', 
onSelect: function() { 
window.location = "/home/view/" + $(this).val().id; }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you populating `select` list from `JSON`?

Comment: try to add the value property to option list and add id as the value

Comment: @MohammadUsman I am populating json value dynamically from db.

Comment: @brk I am not using select option. This json value is got from my search bar field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

When you want to use object array as a source you need to provide the logic for:

1. which object property to use for matching user input
2. which property to use for displaying text of the matching items
3. which property to use when user selects an item

More info:

1. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source
2. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem
3. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

```js
var tags = [
  {"id":1,"name":"JAVA"},
  {"id":2,"name":"cake PHP"},
  {"id":3,"name":"Android"}
];


$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item.name ); // match user request with item.name
          }) );
      },
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#search").val( ui.item.name ); // display user selection in textbox

    console.log('selected: ' + JSON.stringify(ui) );
    console.log('execute window.location = "example.com/' + ui.item.id + '"'); // use id of the selected item to generate required URL
    
  }
});

// provide rendering logic for each matched item
$w = $( "#search" ).data("ui-autocomplete");
$w._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(item) );
    return $( "<li>" )
      .attr( "data-value", item.id )
      .append( item.name )
      .appendTo( ul );
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input id="search">
```

**Edit**: Using typeahead.js as per your comment.

```js
var data =
[
  {"id":1,"name":"JAVA"},
  {"id":2,"name":"cake PHP"},
  {"id":3,"name":"Android"}
];


$(function(){
  var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
    return function(q, cb) {
      var matches, substringRegex;
  
      // an array that will be populated with substring matches
      matches = [];
  
      // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
      substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
  
      // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
      // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
      $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
        if (substrRegex.test(str.name)) {
          matches.push(str);
        }
      });
  
      cb(matches);
    };
  };  

  $('.typeahead').bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
    console.log('Selection: ' + JSON.stringify(suggestion) );
    console.log('execute window.location = "example.com/' + suggestion.id + '"');
  });

  // passing in `null` for the `options` arguments will result in the default
  // options being used
  $('.typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    minLength: 1
  }, {
    source: substringMatcher(data),
    display: 'name'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>

    <div id="prefetch">
      <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="">
    </div>
```

More Info:

- https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md
- https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#the-basics

Comment: I am using typeahead function. If I add something the auto complete result is not working. I update my code in my question. Give me any alternative solution for this

Comment: I've updated the answer with typeahead.js code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the solution as below.

HTML

```
<select id="search">
  <option value="1">JAVA</option>
  <option value="2">cake PHP</option>
  <option value="3">Android</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
document.addEventListener('change', function(){
    window.location = "www.example.com/" + document.getElementById('search').value;
})
```

Comment: Hi, I am not using select option. This json value is got from my search bar field.

Comment: Could you provide an element on HTML, please ?

Comment: this is my html element  `<div class="search-wrap">                          <input id="search" name="search" type="text" class="col-md-12 form-control" placeholder="Search cities..." autocomplete="off" />                               <button class="btn" type="submit"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button></div>`

Comment: from your javascript bind element with "$("#search").autocomplete" right ?

Comment: Yes absolutely correct bind with autocomplete search.

Comment: see the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675069/how-to-get-value-of-selected-item-in-autocomplete .. Hope youe success @ganesh

Comment: This url only set the value in search box. But I want to get the id of this value

Comment: Thank you so much for spending the time to find a solution. But still, I didn't find a solution for my problem. :(

Comment: See another answer from me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Add event select on bind autocomplete.

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        {"id":1,"value":"JAVA"},
        {"id":2,"value":"cake PHP"},
        {"id":3,"value":"Android"}
    ];

    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            window.location = "www.example.com/" + ui.item.id;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have use this code for autocomplete. `<script>
$('#search').typeahead({
ajax: '/searchendpoint/search'
});
</script>` So If I add some thing autocomplete is not working.

Comment: Try this.

$('#search').typeahead({ ajax: '/searchendpoint/search', onSelect: function(item) { window.location = "www.example.com/" + item.id; }});

Comment: yeah.. Its working but id is not passing correctly. https://www.example.com/undefined

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understand your question, but do you mean something like this?

**JSON:**

```
[{"id":1,"name":"JAVA"},{"id":2,"name":"cake PHP"},"id":3,"name":"Android"}]
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
var url = "http://example.com/";

$('#search').change(function() {
  window.location = url + $(this).val().id;
});
</script>
```

Comment: I passed this value but still, I didn't get my id value. `<script>
$('#search').typeahead({ 
ajax: '/searchendpoint/search', 
onSelect: function() { 
window.location = "/home/view/" + $('#search').val().id; }
});
</script>` I getting undifined value in url

Comment: you need to assign the id in your JSON data as value for your select tag first.

Answer (score 1):

onSelect function pass `item`as variable you can use it in select event and it's structure like below

```
{
    value: "1", 
    text: "Toronto"
}
```

and please try below code

```
<script>
$('#search').typeahead({ 
   ajax: '/searchendpoint/search', 
   onSelect: function(item) { 
     //console.log(item);
     window.location = "/home/view/" + item.value; 
   }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "JAVA"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "cake PHP"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Android"
}]

var data_text = [];
var data_obj = [];

$.each(data, function(index, _data) {
    data_text.push(_data.name);
    data_obj[_data.name] = _data;
});

$('#search').typeahead({
    source: data_text,
    updater: function(item) {
        alert(data_obj[item].id)
        window.location = "/home/view/" + data_obj[item].id;
    }
});
```

Comment: how did I mention the var data? because I am calling this data from ajax. `ajax: '/searchendpoint/search'`

Comment: @ganesh from [link](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/blob/master/README.md)

try to change the source : data_text to : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fullmoonfisher/dvLf3pj3/)

Answer (score 1):

This is almost same answer as Vevik but just adjusted version of what the question actually wanted and tried to do. I have tested it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function(){
            var data = [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "JAVA"
            }, {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "cake PHP"
            }, {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Android"
            }];
            var data_labels = [];
            var data_dictionay = [];
            $.each(data, function(index, _data) {
                data_labels.push(_data.name);
                data_dictionay[_data.name] = _data.id;
            });
            $('#search').autocomplete({
                source :  data_labels,
                select: function(ui, item) {
                    if(data_dictionay[item.item.value]){
                        window.location = "/home/view/" + data_dictionay[item.item.value];
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="search" type="text">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am using typeahead function. If I add something into typeahead the auto complete is not working for me..

Comment: You used typehead library ?

Comment: yes my typeahead code is `$('#search').typeahead({ 
                        ajax: '/searchendpoint/search', 
                        onSelect: function() { 
                            window.location = "/home/view/" + $('#search').val(); }
                    });`

Comment: Ok so for typehead you onSelect becomes updater:function(item){ if(data_dictionay[item]){
                        window.location = "/home/view/" + data_dictionay[item];
                    } }

Answer (score 1):

I dont know which typeahead you used, but i try to make an example
Try this:

```js
$('#my-autoc').typeahead({
    name: 'search',
    remote: {
      url: 'https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=%QUERY',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      cache: false,
      filter: function(parsedResponse){
          return (parsedResponse.length > 1) ? parsedResponse[1] : [] ;
      }
    }
  }).on('typeahead:selected', function(e, data){
// its example
//window.location = "http://www.example.com/" + data.value
console.log("window.location = \"http://www.example.com/" + data.value + "\"")

// for your code
//    window.location = "http://www.example.com/" + data.id
  });
```

```css
@import url('https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('https://rawgithub.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css/master/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css');

body{
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/zeMirco/typeahead.js/master/dist/typeahead.min.js"></script>
<form id="my-form">
    <input class="form-control" name="search" type="text" placeholder="type something ..." id="my-autoc">
        <br>
</form>
```

Comment: `https://rawgit.com/ashleydw/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css/master/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css` this url is not correctely 404 error occur

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's `typeahead` uses the properties `label` and `value`.

Try mapping your current array to these before passing it to typeahead.

```
results.map((item) => { 
  return {
    "label": item.name, 
    "value": item.id
  }
}
```